# How to heat treat the back of a moving truck to kill bed bugs

Tags: insulation, heating, pest-control, propane

I'm moving.  My current place has bed bugs.  I don't want to bring them to my new place.  Chemicals take months to kill bed bugs.  Heat treatment takes hours.

If I rent a box truck from U-Haul and leave it in the hot summer sun it should get above the 120F needed to kill bed bugs and their eggs.  Once up to temperature, with all my stuff in it, it will need to stay there for at least 4 hours.

I don't have a lot of stuff.  I'm currently renting a single room in an apartment.  I have a minivan and could take everything in a couple of trips, if not for the bed bugs.  I should be able to lay out everything in open boxes on the floor of the truck so the heat can penetrate easily and I don't have to worry about temperature variations at different heights in the truck.

I can buy a wireless thermometer with a few probes so I can monitor the temperature in various places.

I'm moving to a condo building.  Neither location has a driveway or outdoor outlets I can use.  The only 120v electricity I will have available is 150 Watts from the factory inverter in my 2012 Dodge Grand Caravan.  I can run an extension cord from there into the truck to power a couple of fans to move air around.

Unfortunately, the projected high temperature for the week of my move is 60F, so hot summer sun is not available, and probably won't be for many months.  I'm going to have to provide my own heat.  Electric bed bug heaters typically want four 120v circuits or a 240v oven/dryer receptacle.  Kerosene heaters do not get hot enough to kill bed bugs.

Home Depot rents the RMC-FA60DGP Dyna-Glo Pro 30,000-60,000 BTU propane heater for $17/day.  It needs 0.65a at 120v (78 watts) for its fan and continuous spark ignitor.  A 20lb propane tank should run it on high for about 6 hours.  Unfortunately, it probably limits me to a single box fan inside the truck to stay under 150 watts in total.

I'm worried the oxygen level will drop too low inside the truck if I try to put the propane heater inside it with the propane hose running under the nearly closed door.  I think I can pull the ramp a couple of feet out of the back of the truck, so it stays horizontal in the air, put the heater on top of it, and use double bubble reflective foil insulation (with a hole cut in front of the heater) to cover the opening at the bottom of the door.  With the heater blowing hot air into the center of the truck, I'll have to leave a slit on each end of the foil to let air back out.

I'll probably just sit in the Home Depot parking lot all day.

Any problems with the above?  Suggestions on better ways to accomplish my goal?  Thank you!

Edit to add:

Propane heaters are routinely used to kill bed bugs in houses.  As with anything, common sense is required to use them safely (like not putting the propane tank inside the heated area).  Some quick Google results:

https://prevsol.com/adding-propane-bed-bug-heaters-to-your-toolbox/
https://homeinspectioninsider.com/killing-bed-bugs-using-portable-heater/

Portable enclosures are also often used to kill bed bugs with heat.  More quick Google results:

[https://www.amazon.com/ZappBug-Couches-Time-Tested-Excellent-Customer/dp/B00F67RHWG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00F67RHWG)
https://www.bedbugsupply.com/ThermalStrike-Expedition--Bed-Bug-Heat-Treatment-Box-_p_157.html

Comment: Running a propane heater inside a box truck sounds like an excellent way to burn up the truck and all your worldly belongings.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about home improvement.

Comment: U-Haul and/or Home Depot will probably object to your plans to use their property in this way.

Comment: Agreed, this is not about home improvement, and is a disaster waiting to happen. This should be closed.

Comment: @FreeMan - To be fair, burning up the truck __will__ kill the bed bugs.

Comment: I'm looking at the calendar and wondering about the hot summer sun part

Comment: @TigerGuy not everyone lives in the northern hemisphere

Comment: Everyone who uses farenheit and BTU does,.

Answer (score 2):

Pack your belongings in plastic, but in flat easily heated packages.

Plug in heaters where you live now.

Kill the bedbugs in your room, and belongings. Not nice to leave those for the next person.

Remove your plastic-wrapped belongings to the new location.

Repeat at new location to be extra cautious (as one is inclined to be.)